# UI datepicker hardcoded date value blank on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using UI datepicker.

initial value below "2012-07-08" is not showing when my form loads up. I can select a date but  date inline is not showing.

using latest jquery library and ui stable release.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".datepicker").datepicker();
   $(".datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd"); 
});

<input type="text" name="mydate" id="dp1" class="datepicker" style="width:80px" value="2012-07-08" maxlength="10" />
```

Comment: One thing I notice (though no idea if it makes a difference) is that the dateformat you are giving the datepicker is different to the one in your HTML... Might not be causing the problem but probably wants fixing anyway. :)

Comment: jquery datepicker format yy actually works for yyyy

Answer (score 0):

You can call `datepicker()` and add the option in a single call. This worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
   $(".datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tDaeH/9/

Comment: I already tried that. When I do the date is displayed but clicking the date field does not display the ui datepicker widget.

Comment: can you set a jsfiddle so I can reproduce your issue?